# Composite input to computer monitor

Tags: display, ps2, composite-video

So I have a PS2 that I'd really like to connect to my computer monitor. My monitor only has input for HDMI and VGA, so I can't connect it directly. I have a TV Tuner PCI card (it came with the computer when I got it) that has composite input, but there's a definite lag from it that I simply can't handle, along with serious motion blur. Is there some sort of converter that I could purchase that could solve this? I'm also looking to purchase an additional monitor in the near future, so if there is some monitor that does this better, let me know that as well. Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that any scan converter you find will have some delay.  Used to be a lot of monitors would accept composite, but composite is going the way of the dodo.

Answer (score 1):

You would need what is termed an XGA Box, or a Video to XGA converter.  This could convert the output from the gaming console, to the VGA input your monitor would accept.  There are multiple different products out on the market, and a Google search for either "[XGA Box](https://www.google.com/search?q=xga%20box&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)" or "[Video to XGA](https://www.google.com/search?q=Video%20to%20XGA%20converter&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)" converter will reveal many of them.  At that point, it is just a matter of deciding which one you want to purchase.

Comment: Just to add, you may see adapters and converters, they are not all equal! Analog to Analog should not have any issues either way, but if you ever try to go analog to digital (composite to HDMI for example) you are going to need a converter. A passive "adapter" will work briefly at best. You need a true converter which requires external power and an IC to convert the signal.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a converter that should do it:

[Composite and S-Video to VGA Video Converter for Computer Monitors](http://ca.startech.com/AV/Converters/Video/Video-Game-Jockey-Play-Console-Video-Games-on-your-Computer-Monitor~COMP2VGA)

But it's $80.99 Canadian.

Comment: Try to avoid recommending a single product, as Superuser isn't a shopping recommendation site.  Questions that recommend a *type* of product are allowed.  Questions that require a specific product get closed.

Answer (score -1):

Do a web search for "AV to HDMI" or "RCA to HDMI". There seems to be a good number of converters for this on the market. If you want to buy a "monitor" then you could just look for a TV set with an "AV input", which most seem to have. This is the yellow RCA video jack with the red and white audio jacks. Also, there are still monitors that have composite inputs. Look for "monitor AV input" or "monitor RCA input". I found monitors for CCTV, Raspberry PI, and other applications. These would all work.